# Meteor publish unique user always return nothing or undefined

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, userid

I am wondering why `Meteor.users.find(this.userId);` always return nothing. When I echo on console `this.userId`, it prints it.

Code:

```
    Meteor.publish('login.user', function () {
    if (this.userId) {
        console.log( "current logged in user ---" +this.userId );
        var users = Meteor.users.find( this.userId );
        if ( users && users._id ) {
            console.log( "meteor.users.find() call  --  " +users && users._id );
            return users && users._id;
        }
    }
});
```

console log

```
I20180803-11:59:20.085(1)? current logged in user ---7EQGhuBszukhsYQa3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` doesn't return documents (it returns a cursor). Use `findOne` instead:

```
var users = Meteor.users.findOne( this.userId );
```

Comment: Though had been solved on Meteor forum earlier. Thanks.